# Keras Regression Not predicting High values

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras, regression

I am trying to build a regressor with Keras but it seems my model is not able to predict very high values and hence giving me high (Mean Absolute) loss at the output. Other than that, it can recognize the pattern as shown below.

```
def build_model(features):
# create model
main_input = Input(shape=(len(features[0]),), dtype='float32', name='main_input')
main_out   = Dense(20, kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform", bias_initializer="glorot_uniform", activation='tanh')(main_input)
x = Dropout(0.1)(main_out)
output = Dense(1, name='main_output')(x)
model = Model(inputs=[main_input], outputs=[output])
return model
```

After I normalized both my input and output and edited the model, I still have the problem that my regressor cannot predict very high values.[image]

[image]

Comment: That's probably because of the 'sigmoid' activation in the first layer. You could try without it. Sigmoids have results between 0 and 1. And as it approaches 0 or 1, it gets very low gradients. And probably a dense layer alone after it (a linear layer) cannot deal well with this value compression near 1.

Comment: But I normalized my input data so is it still a problem?

Comment: Probably yes. The problem is between the 'sigmoid' and the layer coming "after" it.

Comment: What activation function fits there best in your opinion? I used linear but it was not more successful.

Comment: I think the rest may be just the model's architecture. Using more layers, LSTM layers, convolutional layers may help.

Comment: Have you normalized your output also?

Comment: Yes I normalized my output but I still have the problem.

Comment: And now network always predicts 24. (Not a magical number- its mean of the output data)